# Thunderbird copy sent mail to selected folder

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am new on Ubuntu and on Thunderbird to which I moved.
Previously, I used Pegasus under Windows. With Pegasus, when sending an email, I could direct the email to a folder/sub-folder of my choice.

I tried several options in Thunderbird → *Account* → *Copies & Folders*, but was not successful.

When sending an email with Thunderbird, how can I copy the email to a folder/sub-folder of my choice?

Comment: Or to explain it otherwise : 

I open Thunderbird.
On the left side, I see under my account name (my email address)  a tree of :
- Inbox
- Drafts
- Templates
- Trash
- and then a list of my own created folders/subfolders

1) I write a message
2) I click on the option "sent"
3) the mail is proceeded to be sent

What I am looking for :
when "clicklng" on "sent", is that Thunderbird would ask me where the mail needs to be put on, the  list of my own created folders/subfolders.


I hope my explanation is more clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Message Filter" to copy or move sent emails to a desired folder.

Select "Message Filters" from the Tools menu. A box will pop up.

Click "New...", enter a descriptive name for the filter, tick the box "after sending", set up your criteria and actions in the boxes below.

If you have questions about how to set up the criteria and actions, leave me a comment below.

Comment: I don't the the OP means that kind of folder.

Comment: Or to explain it otherwise : 

I open Thunderbird.
On the left side, I see under my account name (my email address)  a tree of :
- Inbox
- Drafts
- Templates
- Trash
- and then a list of my own created folders/subfolders

1) I write a message
2) I click on the option "sent"
3) the mail is proceeded to be sent

What I am looking for :
when "clicklng" on "sent", is that Thunderbird would ask me where the mail needs to be put on, the  list of my own created folders/subfolders.


I hope my explanation is more clearer

Comment: Ah then Yes Organic Marble is right, it's just a filter you want. There is a tick box in there for "After Sending". Not a bad step thru here https://www.mailsdaddy.com/blogs/create-set-up-mail-rules-in-mozilla-thunderbird/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Account Settings in Thunderbird Mail.
Click on Local Folders in the tree and yo will see Local Directory: on the right facing page.
You can browse or type the path manually (but create the folder first and set permissions).
For example I use "/home/test/mail_data/thunderbird_local"
That way I can backup the "mail_data" folder and all my email data is there for several applications

Comment: Or to explain it otherwise : 

I open Thunderbird.
On the left side, I see under my account name (my email address)  a tree of :
- Inbox
- Drafts
- Templates
- Trash
- and then a list of my own created folders/subfolders

1) I write a message
2) I click on the option "sent"
3) the mail is proceeded to be sent

What I am looking for :
when "clicklng" on "sent", is that Thunderbird would ask me where the mail needs to be put on, the  list of my own created folders/subfolders.


I hope my explanation is more clearer

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this add-on for Thunderbird for over ten years...:

[Copy Sent to Current](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/copy-sent-to-current/)

Comment: I cannot open the .xpi file

Comment: i used the following steps - without success - : 
    select the Menu (three horizontal lines) icon, click Add-ons, and then click Add-ons again. 
    Select Extensions, Themes, or Plugins (depending on the type of add-on your XPI file contains).
    Click the Gear icon dropdown menu and select Install Add-on From File....
    Navigate to and select your XPI file. Then, click Open.

Comment: Just install it from within Thunderbird: Menu bar > Tools > Add-ons and Themes. Then search for it and click the green button: Add to Thunderbird.